# Values won't to an array with a callback - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-drive-api

I have this code:

```
rtclient.listFiles = function(callback) {
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'maxResults': 20
    }).execute(callback);
  });
}
```

which I try to assign to an array using this code:

```
var arrayStore;

rtclient.listFiles(function(x) {
              for(var i in x.items) {
              arrayStore.push(x.items[i].id);
            }})
```

However, the array `arrayStore` is not storing anything.  This is using the Google Drive API and I am trying to access some file IDs to iterate over.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I should add that `console.log(x.items[i].id)` works in place of the array push

Comment: `arrayStore` is undefined try `var arrayStore = [];`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what Javascript framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the point is you should have a error like:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

because you haven't defined it as an array, the other point is don't use `for(...in)` for arrays, you can find reasons about that in this post:

[Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

```
var arrayStore = [];
rtclient.listFiles(function(x) {
    for(var i = 0; i < x.items.length; i++) {
        arrayStore.push(x.items[i].id);
    }
});
```

The other important point as @toothbrush has commented is, since the Google Drive API is **asynchronous**, you can't access the contents of `arrayStore` immediately, in other word to continue your scenario you should do something like this:

```
var arrayStore = [];
rtclient.listFiles(function(x) {
    for(var i = 0; i < x.items.length; i++) {
        arrayStore.push(x.items[i].id);
    }
    nextStep();
});
function nextStep(){
    //here you would have access to arrayStore
    console.log(arrayStore);
}
```

Comment: Also, you should note that since the Google Drive API is asynchronous, you can't access the contents of `arrayStore` immediately.

Comment: That worked!  What do you mean by the Google Drive API being asynchronous and how does that relate to my example?

Comment: @user2784840: I have considered it in my answer, he means you can't have access right after `listFiles` is called, you should call a function like `nextStep()` to continue your scenario.